# Generating URLs with fromUri and the language prefix, base vs internal

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

What is the recommended way to generate non-route URLs that include the language prefix?

Context: In [CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org), an open source third-party project that integrates with Drupal, we have a function that generates internal URLs (a wrapper over the CMS-specific function).

Since not all URLs referenced have a proper route, so far fromUri has given the best results (rather than fromRoute).

However, the URLs generated by fromUri do not seem to include the language prefix for multi-lingual configurations when using `base` as the prefix. The language prefix is included with `internal`, but if I understand correctly, `internal` should only be used for user-specified links, such as a link field.

Example on a site that has English and French, with French being the default language:

```
print \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri("base:/admin")->toString() . "\n";
print \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri("internal:/admin")->toString() . "\n";
```

```
$ drush scr test.php
/civicrm/dashboard?reset=1
/fr/civicrm/dashboard?reset=1
```

I also tried passing in the `$language` object, but the behaviour is the same:

```
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage();

print \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri("base:/admin", [
  'language' => $language,
])->toString() . "\n";
```

Related question: [Generating arbitrary internal URLs](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207755/generating-arbitrary-internal-urls)

Comment: _internal should only be used for user-specified links, such as a link field_ Do you have a reference for that? The [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromInternalUri/8.6.x) don't appear to mention anything in that vein, just that `internal` is for paths relative to the Drupal/Symfony root

Comment: The [fromUri doc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8.7.x) says: "The internal: scheme should be avoided except when processing actual user input that may or may not correspond to a Drupal route."

Comment: Hmm, not sure I agree with that Just do a search for `'internal:/` in core, there's tons of them being used outside of user input

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I'm still curious why the different behaviour, but for now this helps us move forward.

Comment: Also interestingly, core barely uses `'base:/` by the looks of things; just in tests and a few edge cases. Not really sure what that means exactly though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Drupa8 - as a Symfony application - abstracts paths with routes. So paths may change, the route stays.
- So the cited *"The internal: scheme should be avoided except when processing actual user input that may or may not correspond to a Drupal route."* means: *If you can, use a route.*
- If you can not use routes, the right prefix for routed paths is *internal:*.
- In contrast, *base:* was introduced for use cases like *README.txt* which is unknown to the symfony router and served directly by the web server.

You can find background in these issues, and help improve the docs:

- [Remove the base: scheme in favour of user-path:/internal: [#2422995]](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2422995) which concluded that we still need the base scheme
- [Evaluate and document each use of base: in core [#2417827]](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2417827) which then was started to at least document usages of the base scheme
- [Url::fromUri DocBlock does not mention base: and internal: custom schemes [#2877023]](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2877023) which is about improving the docs

Comment: I've recently seen that Url::fromUri will not add the currently set language if the path is not defined. Here is an example: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/h5p/-/blob/2.0.0/modules/h5peditor/src/H5PEditor/H5PEditorUtilities.php#L141

Is that a bug or feature?